# How to remove properties from object using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

This is my object:

```
var obj = {
  "flag": false,
  "text": "good text",
  "someArray": [
    {
      "questionId": 11,
      "text": "qwe",
      "TypeId": "B",
      "source": "oooooo"
    },
    {
      "questionId": 12,
      "text": "zxc",
      "TypeId": "A",
      "source": "pppppp"
    },
    {
      "questionId": 13,
      "text": "asd",
      "TypeId": "D",
      "source": "cccccc"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is remove from objects in `someArray` properties `TypeId` and `source`. How can I do this with lodash? I was trying using _.pick, but I don't know how can I use this inside `someArray`.

Comment: why not do it with native JS?

Comment: Is it simple and elegant as with lodash?

Comment: Just `.map` over the array with your `_.pick` function

Comment: @DiPix, you may try my solution if it suits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the opposite of `_.pick`, which is `_.omit` and return the objects without the given properties by mapping them with `_.map`

```js
var obj = {
  "flag": false,
  "text": "good text",
  "someArray": [{
    "questionId": 11,
    "text": "qwe",
    "TypeId": "B",
    "source": "oooooo"
  }, {
    "questionId": 12,
    "text": "zxc",
    "TypeId": "A",
    "source": "pppppp"
  }, {
    "questionId": 13,
    "text": "asd",
    "TypeId": "D",
    "source": "cccccc"
  }]
}

obj.someArray = _.map(obj.someArray, o => _.omit(o, ['TypeId', 'source']));

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```